# map2_dbl() throws an error while alone, but not in combination with dplyr::mutate()

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have this matrix and I want to use `purrr::map2_dbl()` to perform a function on each row - let's say to add- now, the following works:

```
add_2 <- function(a, b) a + b

sim <- tibble(
    a = 1:4,
    b = 5:8
)

sim %>% mutate(sum = map2_dbl(a, b, add_2))
```

HOWEVER, when I use `map2_dbl()` alone, it throws an error:

```
sim %>% map2_dbl(a, b, add_2)
Error in as_function(.f, ...) : object 'b' not found
```

I cannot understand why; also, it's interesting that `pmap_dbl()` works just fine.

```
sim %>% pmap_dbl(add_2) # 6, 8, 10, 12
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can do `map2_dbl(sim$a, sim$b, add_2)`

Comment: Thanks, and yes. But isn't it that `sim %>% map2_dbl(a, b, add_2)` and `map2_dbl(sim$a, sim$b, add_2)` are basically the same? Why the earlier throws cannot find 'b'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the first works inside `mutate` because the variables `a` and `b` are visible within the scope. That is, `mutate` is making `sim$a` available as `a`, etc for the other columns. This is a function of `mutate`, not the `%>%` pipe.

The literal equivalent of `sim %>% map2_dbl(a, b, add_2)` is `map2_dbl(sim, a, b, add_2)`, which I hope now clears up why that form does not work. You need the first two arguments to map to two vectors, as @akrun's comment provides.

Perhaps you would prefer:

```
with(sim, map2_dbl(a, b, add_2))
# [1]  6  8 10 12
```

or

```
within(sim, { mysum = map2_dbl(a, b, add_2) })
# # A tibble: 4 × 4
#       a     b   sum mysum
#   <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     5     6     6
# 2     2     6     8     8
# 3     3     7    10    10
# 4     4     8    12    12
```

Neither `with` nor `within` are `tidyverse` functions, though they do provide some easier-to-read code at times.

`sim %>% pmap_dbl(add_2)`, which is equivalent to `pmap_dbl(sim, add_2)`, works because the first argument to `pmap*` functions is a `list`, and since `sim` is a `tibble`, it inherits `data.frame` which is just a `list` where the elements are vectors (or `list`s) of equal lengths. Your call is equivalent to `pmap_dbl(list(sim$a, sim$b), add_2)` (verbose and overkill, sure).

Comment: Well explained. Other possibilities include `sim %>% { map2_dbl(.$a, .$b, add_2) }`, and `sim %$% map2_dbl(a, b, add_2)`.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the piping

```
sim %>% 
    map2_dbl(a, b, add_2)
```

translates to:

```
map2_dbl(.x = sim, .y = a, .f = b, ... = add_2)
```

which does not make sense, and indeed the error warns `b` does not exists.

---

Similarly

```
sim %>% 
    pmap_dbl(add_2)
```

translates to:

```
pmap_dbl(.l = sim, .f = add_2)
```

which does work.

---

Comment: Thanks @GGamba. Got it. :-)

Comment: I think it translates to `map2_dbl(.x = sim, .y = a, .f = b, ... = add_2)`. Your translation would need the exposition pipe.